# Get rid of white screen at startup

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, splash-screen

I've been searching online for the right way to avoid the white screen - replacing it with a splashscreen - when my Android app launches.
I found solutions that uses styles like

```
<style name="AppTheme.SplashTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

But in my case this only delays the view appearance, acting as the app doesn't work (the view inflates after a couple of seconds). I do not want some view that lasts for some seconds I've decided, I just want to replace the blank screen to something custom while my app needs to load.
The only way to have the desired behaviour was to place a drawable as a background in the style of my SplashscreenActivity.

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
```

Now, I would like not to place an image as a background-because of the different resolutions of screens- but to set an xml layout.
Is this possible? What's the best way to get rid of the blank screen without delaying the view appearance?

Answer (score 2):

You should do it as follows

- create an xml file in `res/drawable` folder with below content. This will act as your splash screen. Let's name it `splash.xml`

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" />
     <item>
          <bitmap android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
      android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
  </layer-list>
  ```
- Then you need to specify a `style/theme` without titlebar for your splash view, so add below `style` to your `style.xml` file.

  ```
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
  </style>
  ```
- In `AndroidManifest.xml` change `theme` of your `launcher activity` to use `SplashTheme`

  ```
      <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  ```
- Finally in that `launcher activity` (in my example `MainActivity`) change the theme back to default application theme, usually named `AppTheme`

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
      ...
  }
  ```

That's it! Now run your application and see that there is no white screen anymore.

References: I used [this post](https://android.jlelse.eu/launch-screen-in-android-the-right-way-aca7e8c31f52) and [this one](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/create-a-splash-screen-on-android-the-right-way-93d6fb444857) to provide the above code example.

Comment: In splash xml I cannot place LinearLayouts, Fabs or other components right? Because I wanted my splashscreen to look like the MainActivity

Comment: No, I guess you cann't. If you use a layout with such items, it needs time to be created when app first started and hence white screen appears again.

Comment: So if i need a screen splitted in 4 different colors?

Comment: please explain what you mean. I didn't get it.

Comment: I need my splashscreen to look like my main Activity, so a layout splitted in 4 different colors with a logo in the middle

Comment: The problem is that loading an xml layout when application does its cold start will take a few seconds and that's why user will see a withe screen while app is loading. If you want to avoid this white screen, you can load a lightweight style file as explained in above answer. But loading your main layout without any delay (that result in having a withe screen) is not possible(as far as I know). By above solution you may use a picture which has 4 colors and a logo in the middle as the background picture of your splash screen although this is misleading since user can't have interaction with it.

Comment: (continue of above comment): It is misleading because user may think your application is loaded instantly but it is in fact a picture and not real layout of the activity. That can drive people mad!